# Parse CSS expression with regex

Tags: c++, css, regex, c++11

As the title says i have a problem understanding `std::regex`, or rather, regexes (with ECMAScript syntax) in general. What i want to do is parse an extremely simple CSS file - one that looks like so:

```
.some_class {
    margin: 12px;
}
```

but that may also look like this:

```
.some_class 
{
    margin: 12px;
}
```

To summarize, i am looking to parse this "grammar":

```
$selector$ {
    $declaration$ : $value$;
    $declaration$ : $value$;
    ...
}
```

How would one go about this? Won't whitespaces break a regex, or is there some agnostic regex syntax to achieve the above? I am looking to parse a CSS file into a set of rules, for my own custom HTML renderer that i am writing for learning purposes; I'm just having a hard time understanding how regexes work. Thanks for any helpful answer/comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\s` means whitespace and `\s*` means zero or more occurrence of whitespace

this is what you are looking for:

```
((:?\.*|#*)+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\s*{[^}]*})
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lR4aW1/3

Comment: will this work for any sort of declaration/value combination like this? Imagine this scenario: `h3, .heading3  { border: 3px solid red; }`, or would i need to define a seperate expression to search for that?

Comment: @calcyss feel free to enter more css classes in the demo to see if they match

Comment: Fromt the looks of it, and after testing, this doesn't seem to handle multiple selectors (i.e., with `,`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107115/discussion-between-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani-and-calcyss).